# Meteor 0.5.0 examples not running on Windows

Tags: meteor

Fresh install of Meteor 0.5.0 on Windows Vista. I don't get the basic examples working. No success after creating the empty'ish hello app either. The shell is running as admin. Meteor recognises that I changed a source file, but then nothing. It doesn't matter where in the filesystem i try this. Always getting

```
Exited with code: -1073741819:
```

eg

```
C:\Users\jawford\Meteor Apps\Examples>meteor create starter3
starter3: created.

To run your new app:
   cd starter3
   meteor

C:\Users\jawford\Meteor Apps\Examples>cd starter3

C:\Users\jawford\Meteor Apps\Examples\starter3>meteor
[[[[[ C:\Users\jawford\Meteor Apps\Examples\starter3 ]]]]]

Running on: http://localhost:3000/
Exited with code: -1073741819
Exited with code: -1073741819
Exited with code: -1073741819
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.
Exited with code: -1073741819
Exited with code: -1073741819
Exited with code: -1073741819
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y

C:\Users\jawford\Meteor Apps\Examples\starter3>
```

Comment: How did you install meteor? http://win.meteor.com?

Comment: Yes exactly, downloaded and launched the msi, no hassle at all.

Answer (score 4):

If you run into this problem using Windows 8, you will need to change compatibility mode for the node executable.

- Go to the folder where you installed Meteor
- Open properties for bin/node.exe
- Set compatibility mode for Windows 7

You should now be able to start the application as you did earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with Fibers not loading correctly. You can attempt to run `app/meteor/meteor.js` with `bin/node`, both are in the Meteor directory in Program Files. This could maybe give you more details why it is crashing. It might also be handy to run the tests in the `lib/node_modules/fibers` folder which might point out why Fibers is misbehaving.

Answer (score 1):

The exit code -1073741819 corresponds to C0000005 which indicates an access violation.

Many users find that setting compatibility mode to "Windows 7" solves that problem, but it doesn't always and there is some evidence that it also occurs on Windows 7.

Investigating a later issue on win Meteor 0.5.9, I discovered a problem with fibers on windows that may explain this issue, and I have a tentative fix.

Please see: https://github.com/TomWij/meteor/issues/66#issuecomment-15994548 for further details.